# multivariable calculus changing to uv plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

1.)$f(x)$ is continuous in  $0\le x\le a$, prove that :

$$\iint_Df(x+y) dx dy= \int_{0}^{a} x f(x) dx$$
where $D=\{(x,y)|x \geq 0, y \geq 0, x+y \le a\}$

i try to change variable to u and v coordinate
$x+y=v$ and $u=x$ 
  According to the domain if i draw in xy plane , it is a triangle in first quadrant with equation $y=-x+a$ so D = $0 \le x \le a$ & $0 \le x+y \le a$

but my book said that the domain is $0 \le x \le a$ ,  $x \le x+y \le a$,
how can i get this domain?

and then find jacobian from $u=x$ and $v=x+y$.

$$\det\bigg(\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0\\
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\bigg) =1$$ 
 
 
is it correct? and for this problem is it necessary to change variable to $uv$ plane? thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your domain $D$ is a triangular region in the first quadrant bounded by the three lines $x=0$, $y=0$ and $x+y=a$. You can view this as a region bounded on the left and right by two vertical lines $x=0$ and $x=a$, hence $$0\leq x\leq a.$$ It is bounded below and above by the lines $y=0$ and $x+y=a$ or $y=a-x$. So $0\leq y\leq a-x$ which, after adding $x$ everywhere, is the same thing as $$x\leq x+y\leq a.$$

Comment: thankyou so much!!! now I understand where the substitution came from!!!!  so for this kind problem, is it better to always draw the region first? then analyze like what you did?

Comment: Yes I would try to draw the region first and then see the bounds of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: thankyou so much!!!!!!!!! :D